# How TypeScript handle mapped type like this?

Tags: typescript

I was writing an generic `DeepReadonly` type:

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: true;
};

type A1 = DeepReadonly<number>;
type A2 = DeepReadonly<string>;
type A3 = DeepReadonly<boolean>;
type A4 = DeepReadonly<symbol>;
type A5 = DeepReadonly<never>;
type A6 = DeepReadonly<null>;
type A7 = DeepReadonly<undefined>;
type A8 = DeepReadonly<bigint>;
type A9 = DeepReadonly<void>;
type A10 = DeepReadonly<{a: string}>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgEoQIYBMD2A7ANiAPACoB8UAvFAN4BQUdUATqpriFANoAKUAlllAGsIIDADMohALoAuKMAYBXCAG5qAX1XVQkKAEEAjACNyg4WKhYFAW0MQGq7dF0AmYxSEjxAZ3l8A5g7gTgDMbqaeUIYYGDioWIE6ugAsYR7mXiA2MQlOAKypZuJYEABudjl6AGwFEShYIBW6AAw15oY8fnzAjQDsreIKWAJYGADu8VpBegAc-RYKODiNAJxzg2gQonwQaJqOevomcAjI6Nh4+JY2dsSNzkfwSMznBD4M-reTicEPJ8+s+CiMTin32yV+TzOAIyWRwoKmulyENOLAuxTKDHhiUqyP+aIWcN6uKhF3Wm22aCxTmmxNRBHanSwwCpemWtJe+BKGB4lMa+ia7IBlBQsje-jUny+0GOkLp+iIpHchQkUAgAA9gBAsGgvBZSnZaFAAPwSQ2ySiMPFsdgCXj8NLiKSyGUojmEG2SUhqahSg4oQV4eVXWyYu7+iguq3ysVYPws3TBcOwR6u1jyoGxOrxpJJyMkkDRzJRQm+xG5lNRy760Olyrlv75+V1EDxnr12UvIME+PTdupwP4MlbYq8n0+-aIQ4Riv5y7d5RAA)

I found out that `A1~A9` is parameter type it self.
How TypeScript handle this kind of mapped type?
My guessing: if the `keyof T` is `never`, the whole mapped type is discarded and `T` is returned.

I found the function `resolveMappedTypeMembers` in [`checker.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/compiler/checker.ts).
But did find more useful information though.

Can someone explain this with TypeScript source code?
Thanks.

UPDATE：

Thanks for the author of voted answer. I found the function `instantiateMappedType`  in TypeScript source code where the algorithm is well explained:

```
function instantiateMappedType(type: MappedType, mapper: TypeMapper, aliasSymbol?: Symbol, aliasTypeArguments?: readonly Type[]): Type {
            // For a homomorphic mapped type { [P in keyof T]: X }, where T is some type variable, the mapping
            // operation depends on T as follows:
            // * If T is a primitive type no mapping is performed and the result is simply T.
            // * If T is a union type we distribute the mapped type over the union.
            // * If T is an array we map to an array where the element type has been transformed.
            // * If T is a tuple we map to a tuple where the element types have been transformed.
            // * Otherwise we map to an object type where the type of each property has been transformed.
            // For example, when T is instantiated to a union type A | B, we produce { [P in keyof A]: X } |
            // { [P in keyof B]: X }, and when when T is instantiated to a union type A | undefined, we produce
            // { [P in keyof A]: X } | undefined.
            const typeVariable = getHomomorphicTypeVariable(type);
            if (typeVariable) {
                const mappedTypeVariable = instantiateType(typeVariable, mapper);
                if (typeVariable !== mappedTypeVariable) {
                    return mapTypeWithAlias(getReducedType(mappedTypeVariable), t => {
                        if (t.flags & (TypeFlags.AnyOrUnknown | TypeFlags.InstantiableNonPrimitive | TypeFlags.Object | TypeFlags.Intersection) && t !== wildcardType && t !== errorType) {
                            if (!type.declaration.nameType) {
                                if (isArrayType(t)) {
                                    return instantiateMappedArrayType(t, type, prependTypeMapping(typeVariable, t, mapper));
                                }
                                if (isGenericTupleType(t)) {
                                    return instantiateMappedGenericTupleType(t, type, typeVariable, mapper);
                                }
                                if (isTupleType(t)) {
                                    return instantiateMappedTupleType(t, type, prependTypeMapping(typeVariable, t, mapper));
                                }
                            }
                            return instantiateAnonymousType(type, prependTypeMapping(typeVariable, t, mapper));
                        }
                        return t;
                    }, aliasSymbol, aliasTypeArguments);
                }
            }
            // If the constraint type of the instantiation is the wildcard type, return the wildcard type.
            return instantiateType(getConstraintTypeFromMappedType(type), mapper) === wildcardType ? wildcardType : instantiateAnonymousType(type, mapper, aliasSymbol, aliasTypeArguments);
        }
```

UPDATE:

I managed to build a local TypeScript and be able to debug tsserver.js

Place a breakpoint on following function and then hover on `A1`(`type A1 = DeepReadonly<number>`). Step through the code.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the update! I wish I could give you more than one upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot give you an answer citing TypeScript source code, but this case is mentioned in the [FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#common-bugs-that-arent-bugs):

> *This mapped type returns a primitive type, not an object type.*
>
> Mapped types declared as `{ [ K in keyof T ]: U }` where `T` is a type parameter are known as homomorphic mapped types, which means that the mapped type is a structure preserving function of `T`. When type parameter `T` is instantiated with a primitive type the mapped type evaluates to the same primitive.

Comment: Thank you for the keyword 'homomorphic'. I searched throughout TypeScript source code and finally found the function `instantiateMappedType`: https://github1s.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/compiler/checker.ts#L16116-L16152